# Why am I getting null when trying to decode file from URL to post to Facebook from Android app

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap

This is my code:

```
        byte[] data;
        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myImageUrl);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();
```

A detail is that, in logcat, I see this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: <Image URL> (No such file or directory)
```

After this, I get null pointer exception because the variavle bi is null. But the url contains my image. Why this happens?

Thank you!

Comment: This link states that it the method returns null if it isn't a file or can't be decoded. Are you sure you don't have more useful information in the logcat?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)

Comment: I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767199/bitmapfactory-decodefilestring-imagepath-returns-null-even-image-exists. And  here another that can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537105/bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null